# Excel macro for automatic data entry

Tags: vba, excel

I need a macro to help me with data entry in Excel. Basically I want `sheet 1` for data entry, and `sheet 2` for the data that are entered. `Sheet 1` will only have one row for data entry, and once that row is filled you hit enter. The row is automatically added to the table in `sheet 2`, and the row is cleared on `sheet 1`. Now you are ready to enter another entry in `sheet 2`.

So to summarize `sheet 2` will have multiple rows for the data entered, and `sheet 1` will only have 1 row because it automatically clears it's row after each entry.

Is something like this possible?? If you guys can post some code for me it would really help, and keep in mind I have never programmed in VBA before. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Place a button on your sheet 1, then put this macro into a regular code module and attach it to your button.  Assuming you are entering values across row2 (row1 being titles or such), then this would transfer row2 data to the next empty row on sheet2:

```
Sub Transfer()
    Rows(2).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    Rows(2).ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: This works and you could tie it to a range and make the button unnecessary. on each tab to the next cell, and once the last cell column is hit you could trigger this and reset to the beginning

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure of the use-case, but have you considered using Excel UserForms instead.

The input would be a form that actually appears in front of the user which would collect input.  When they hit the enter button, you could have underlying code to update the main sheet, Sheet 2.

http://www.excel-vba-easy.com/vba-userform-excel-vba.html

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the database form. set up your database sheet then Data > Form (in 2003)

Answer (score 0):

In order not to have to "click" on a button, I would suggest to look into this function:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

This macro will run every time something in your sheet has changed.
It might be that you have to check if there is data in cell A1, as this VBA might be triggered both after hitting enter and after the data has been transported to the other sheet.